# not able to give target to javascript document.write();

Tags: javascript, php, html

Since I am a rookie to javascript, I am calling javascript function using onclick event and then I am calling php function in document.write(); using javascript, In my program there are 4 frames. Link texts are printing in the 2nd frame so I want print whatever the output comes from php using document.write(); in 3rd frame. Is it possible?? If so how can I achieve this?? Thanks in advance..

```
**js.php**

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $variable="link";
        for($i=1; $i<4; $i++)
        {
            echo "<a id='demo' href='' ondblclick='trial();'>".$variable."<br></a>";
            if($i==3)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    ?>

    <script>
        function trial()
        {
            //var parameter1="<?php echo $i ?>";
            //document.write(parameter1);
            parent.table.location.document.write("<?php include 'linkjs.php'; hello($i); ?>");
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>

**linkjs.php**

<?php

    function hello($num)
    {
        echo $num;
    }

?>

**frame.php**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <frameset rows="13%,87%,*%">
        <frame src="" scrolling=no >
        <frameset cols="20%,80%,*%" >

          <frame src="js.php" name="tree" >

            <frameset rows="40%,60%,*%">
              <frame src="" name="table" scrolling=yes >
              <frame src="" name="graph" scrolling=no >  
            </frameset>

        </frameset>
    </frameset>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store frame name in a js variable and then variable_name.document.write(); thats it...

```
<script>
    function trial()
    {
        var framename=parent.frames['framename'];
        framename.document.write("<?php include 'linkjs.php'; hello($i); ?>");

    }
 </script>
```